# Windows 7 RTM IPSec VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, rtm, ipsec

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate RTM 64Bit and need an IPSec VPN client, I've tried Shrew VPN but that caused a BSOD.

I've noticed there is a VPN option in the start menu but I'm not sure if it is IPSec capable.

If it's not what other clients could you recommend?

Cheers
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the RC version of [Shrew VPN 2.1.5-rc-2](http://www.shrew.net/download/vpn) works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be several, NCP Secure Entry Client touts Windows 7 compatibility for instance.

As far as the built-in VPN client it supports several standards including IPsec since like NT4 or atleast Windows 2000 days but from what I know some features are missing which makes it not always compatible - but it's [worth a shot](http://www.publicvpn.com/support/Vista.php).

Windows and Windows domains uses IPSec natively to secure traffic so it's not like it's not there, just that the client-side part might not be as flexible as an enthusiast user might want - normally it'll be configured by administrators with ipsec policies internally on a company network...

Comment: Well I'll give the built in client a shot then the NCP, I'll get back and report my status - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shrew 2.1.5-rc3 worked for me, I also wrote a basic configuration tutorial [here](http://read-stuff-here.blogspot.com/2009/09/shrew-vpn-tutorial-on-windows-64-bit.html)